# Adding a class to Rails select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, select

I am working with the spree engine and want to change all the select tags style. so i want to add a class to this select. i am working in rails 3.2 and ruby 2.0.0-p0. the file is in html.erb

```
<%= select "search", filter[:scope], labels.insert(0, [filter_title(filter[:name]), nil]), selected: params[:search][filter[:scope]] %>
```

I have tried

```
<%= select "search", filter[:scope], labels.insert(0, [filter_title(filter[:name]), nil]), selected: params[:search][filter[:scope]], {:class => "select2"} %>
```

This breaks with `_filters.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
...cope]], {:class => "select2"} );@output_buffer.safe_concat('`

```
<%= select "search", filter[:scope], labels.insert(0, [filter_title(filter[:name]), nil]), selected: params[:search][filter[:scope]], :class => "select2" %>
```

This runs but won't add the class to the select tag

```
<%= select( filter[:scope], labels.insert(0, [filter_title(filter[:name]), nil]), selected: params[:search][filter[:scope]], {:prompt => "search"}, {:class => "select2"} )%>
```

This breaks with `_filters.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...scope]], {:prompt => "search"}, {:class => "select2"}));@out...`

I have gone through [the api on rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) for `FormOptionsHelper` but it seems i am working with an older syntax of rails for the select tag. i cant figure this out anyone have the same issue?

Comment: `select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { include_blank: true }, {class: "yourclass"})` this is the format

Comment: Yeah i read the API. the only thing is how do i convert `<%= select "search", filter[:scope], labels.insert(0, [filter_title(filter[:name]), nil]), selected: params[:search][filter[:scope]] %>` into that format

Comment: I  do not know labels .insert why cant you add a array over there like `labels`.... `<%= select "search", filter[:scope], labels, {selected: params[:search][filter[:scope]]}, {class: "class"} %>`

Comment: thats not the issue the select works fine. just adding the class is the issue. adding {class: => "class"} wont resolve

Comment: look at my comment  `{selected: params[:search][filter[:scope]]}, {class: "class"}` it is the last parameters not only class all html options

Comment: worked??..............

Comment: oh balls you changed the hash pointer.. it seems to be working now thanks man

Comment: createda post please vote me up thank ss

Answer (score 0):

your select should be like below:--

`<%= select "search", filter[:scope], labels, {selected: params[:search][filter[:scope]]}, {class: "class"} %>`

Or specific

`{selected: params[:search][filter[:scope]]}, {class: "class"}` it is the last parameters

Comment: @ŁukaszLech post updated he was giving me thanks for working but do not vote me up